# Spacing between words

Tags: spacing

I would like to increase the spacing between each word in the last line of each paragraph.

I am using the command {\hbox spread 10pt{...}} to achieve this, but noticed that the space between words is not constant depending of the length of the last line. For example, a short last line will have larger spaces between words than a longer line, even though the same hbox with the same parameters is used.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: how are you adding hbox??? by hand after you see where tex breaks the line?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. I enclosed by hand the last line of each paragraph into a \hbox

Comment: why?........... what would you do if the natural length did not leave 10pt?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because I feel that the spacing between words in the core of the paragraph is substantially larger than the one displayed in the last line.

Comment: that is not, in general, the case.

Comment: I'd approach this in a different way.  Determine how much wider you would like each of those spaces to be, multiply by the number of words less one, then, after the last word, insert `\hspace{-<number of words times extra space per word space>}`.  Not tested.  (Actually, I wouldn't do this myself.)

Comment: @Beginner with the default `\parfillskip` the last line is set to its natural width, other lines may have spaces stretched or shrunk to justify the text. So on average the final line should be the same as the others, always stretching by 10pt seems very wrong

Comment: `\lastlinefit=1000` would stretch the last line according to the stretch and shrink of the preceding line.

Comment: @Robert ooh I'd totally forgotten that pdftex addition. Do you want to post an answer as I guess that _is_ the answer. (my posted answer is the pure texbook version)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle etex even... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can adjust the stretch on the last line by adjusting `\parfillskip`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\qq{\smash{\kern-1pt\rule[-5cm]{1pt}{5cm}}}
\begin{document}

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.\qq

\setlength\parfillskip{0pt plus \textwidth}% always safe but only slight stretch
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.\qq


\setlength\parfillskip{0pt plus .5\textwidth}% more stretch but may cause underfull boxes
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.\qq
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

etex introduced the (rarely used) command `\lastlinefit`, which will adjust the stretch and shrink components in the last line according to those in the preceding one: it accepts  values between 0 and 1000, where 0 means that the line will be typeset at its natural width, 1000 means that it will be typeset with the same interword spaces as the preceding line; any values between 0 and 1000 will be an interpolation of the two extremes.

Putting `\lastlinefit=1000` (or `500` or whatever your prefer) into your preamble should therefore solve your problem.

Comment: +1 I can live without another green tick